# remove rows that don't contain names in another data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like below, we'll call statesA (but with all 50 states). I have a separate data frame that has specific states in one column (37 states), we'll call statesB (no ozone column). How can I remove all information in the rows from statesA to contain only the states from statesB? I want to keep the ozone number though for the 37 states.

```
`    state           ozone
     <chr>           <dbl>
50  Alabama     0.04537190      
1   Alaska      0.02505039      
12  Arizona     0.05191860      
23  Arkansas    0.03815530      
34  California  0.03625556      
45  Colorado    0.04462810      
47  Connecticut 0.04976119      
48  Delaware    0.04170330      
49  Florida     0.04038279      
2   Georgia     0.04970213`
```

I was referred to another question and tried to do a right outer join but only received 25 of the needed 37 rows.
`statesC = merge(x = statesA, y = statesB, by = "state", all.y = TRUE)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: user an inner-join on the two data sets. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/5977215)

Comment: I tried to do a right outer join but only received 25 of the needed 37 rows. `statesC = merge(x = statesA, y = statesB, by = "state", all.y = TRUE)`

Comment: why didn't you do an inner-join?

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I finally realized it was a stupid error earlier in my code.

Comment: we all make them :)